# ¿Por qué no detecta el teclado en OpenGL 3.3?

Tags: c++, opengl

Es la primera vez que interactúo con OpenGL 3.3, y básicamente lo que tengo que hacer es que al apretar la tecla "R" la ventana cambie de color, y lo mismo para la tecla "L". Esta es una parte del código que hice:

```
glViewport(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);
printf("Hola mundo");

if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_R) == GLFW_PRESS) {
    printf("Cambiando color");
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);

}

if (glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_L) == GLFW_PRESS)
    glClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);
```

La pantalla se queda con el primer 'glClearColor' y sí imprime "Hola Mundo".
Pero cuando presiono la tecla "R" o "L" no pasa nada :C
¿Me está faltando algo o saben si hice algo mal?

Lo intenté con las respuestas que me compartieron pero el resultado es este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estás recordando llamar `glfwPollEvents`?

Answer (score 2):

Según la documentación de [`glfwGetKey`](https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__input.html#gadd341da06bc8d418b4dc3a3518af9ad2) (traducción y resaltado míos):

> Esta función devuelve **el último estado informado por la tecla especificada** a la ventana especificada. El estado devuelto es `GLFW_PRESS` o `GLFW_RELEASE`. La acción de alto nivel `GLFW_REPEAT` sólo se informa desde la *callback* de tecla.

Muy posiblemente el programa estará devolviendo `GLFW_PRESS` durante un espacio de tiempo muy corto que no coincide con el momento en que se lee el valor, inmediatamente después de haber informado de `GLFW_PRESS` el valor queda en estado `GLFW_RELEASE`, intenta cambiar el código de la siguiente forma:

```
glViewport(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);
std::cout << "Hola mundo";

const auto R = glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_R);
if (R == GLFW_PRESS || R == GLFW_RELEASE) {
    std::cout << "Cambiando color";
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);
}

const auto L = glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_L);
if (L == GLFW_PRESS || L == GLFW_RELEASE) {
    glClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);
}
```

Puedes generalizar el código de la siguiente manera:

```
void cambiaColor(GLFWwindow *window, int key, GLfloat r, GLfloat g, GLfloat b, GLfloat a) {
    switch (glfwGetKey(window, key)) {
        case GLFW_PRESS:
        case GLFW_RELEASE:
            glClearColor(r, g, b, a);
    }
}

glViewport(0, 0, screenWidth, screenHeight);
glClearColor(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);
std::cout << "Hola mundo";

cambiaColor(window, GLFW_KEY_R, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);
cambiaColor(window, GLFW_KEY_L, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.4f, 0.0f);
```

Comment: Utilice ambas respuestas que me compartiste, pero ahora sólo se queda con el último "glClearColor". Sigue sin detectar las teclas cuando quiero cambiar de color :/

Comment: Entonces lo que quieres hacer es que el color cambie al **mantener pulsada** la tecla, no al pulsar la tecla. ¿es así?

Answer (score 0):

Con el código que muestras es difícil determinar el error con exactitud. Existen dos opciones.

1. La función que evalúa el estado de la tecla no se ejecuta en un bucle infinito, por lo que sólo se evalúa en el arranque del programa.
2. Estas usando doble buffer y no realizas el Swap Buffers. Con lo que estás renderizando el buffer posterior y nunca se hace visible.

En esta URL tienes un ejemplo con un bucle infinito, donde se realiza el cambio de buffer, y se llama a una función callback al pulsar una tecla.
https://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/quick_guide.html#quick_key_input
En la función key_callback deberías modificar una variable, y en el bucle de renderización realizar la llamada a glClearColor con un color u otro en función de dicha variable.